# using rnn_cell inside of tf.while getting ValueError: The two structures don't have the same number of elements

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Given `data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, None, 3])` (batch_size * time_step * feature_size), Ideally I want do `tf.unstack(data, axis = 1)` to get a number of tensors each of which has the shape of `[2,3]` so later feed them to a rnn with a for loop like

```
for rnn_input in rnn_inputs:
    state = rnn_cell(rnn_input, state)
```

Using high-level API like tf.nn.dynamic_rnn is off the table so I create a work around like

```
import tensorflow as tf


data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, None, 3])

step_number = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, None)

loop_counter_inital = tf.constant(0)

initi_state = tf.zeros([2,3], tf.float32)

def while_condition(loop_counter, rnn_states):
    return loop_counter < step_number

def while_body(loop_counter, rnn_states):
    loop_counter_current = loop_counter

    current_states = tf.gather_nd(data, tf.stack([tf.range(0, 2), tf.zeros([2], tf.int32)+loop_counter_current], axis=1))     

    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(3)

    rnn_states = cell(current_states, rnn_states)

    return [loop_counter_current, rnn_states]


_, _states = tf.while_loop(while_condition, while_body, 
                   loop_vars=[loop_counter_inital, initi_state], 
                   shape_invariants=[loop_counter_inital.shape, tf.TensorShape([2, 3])])

with tf.Session() as sess:    

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print (sess.run(_states, feed_dict={data:[[[3,1,6],[4,1,2]],[[5,8,1],[0,5,2]]], step_number:2 }))
```

The idea is to loop through each row in each of the 2D tensor of `data` to get the features for each time step. I got a error

```
First structure (2 elements): [<tf.Tensor 'while/Identity:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'while/Identity_1:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=float32>]

Second structure (3 elements): [<tf.Tensor 'while/Identity:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, (<tf.Tensor 'while/basic_rnn_cell/Tanh:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'while/basic_rnn_cell/Tanh:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=float32>)]
```

There seems to be some related posts. None actually worked. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know every `BasicRNNCell` will implement `call()` with the signature `(output, next_state) = call(input, state)`. This means that your result is a list of shapes `((?,unit),(?,unit))`. So you need to do as follows.

```
rnn_states = cell(current_states, rnn_states)[1]
```

You also made a mistake here. You forgot to add 1 to `loop_counter_current`.

```
return [loop_counter_current+1, rnn_states]
```

**Add**

**First structure** represents the initial value of parameter `loop_vars` you passed in, which contains the initial values of `loop_counter_inital` and `initi_state`. So its structure corresponds to the following.

```
[
<tf.Tensor 'while/Identity:0' shape=() dtype=int32>  #---> loop_counter_inital
, <tf.Tensor 'while/Identity_1:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=float32>  #---> initi_state
]
```

**Second structure** represents the parameter `loop_vars` after a loop. Its results correspond to the following based on previous errors.

```
[
<tf.Tensor 'while/Identity:0' shape=() dtype=int32>  #---> loop_counter_inital
, (<tf.Tensor 'while/basic_rnn_cell/Tanh:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=float32>  #---> output
, <tf.Tensor 'while/basic_rnn_cell/Tanh:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=float32>)  #---> initi_state
]
```

Comment: Good, thanks, anyway what does the first, second structure refers to?

Comment: @user1935724 I added it to the answer.